# Recursively building page menu from array within the same function

Tags: php, arrays, func

I'm looking to build a new menu for my website to utilize seo friendly urls instead of page ids however i have run into an issue building the menu dynamically.

Previously our menu was made using a recursive MySQL function which would grab all the contents and recursively build the menu adding in the html where required and outputting the results however this time i would like to have PHP and an array generate the menu.

Basically i pull all the pages from the database and insert them into an array which is called by $this->ApplicationPages however with the below function i come across 2 issues.

**issue 1**

I can only go 2 levels deep were as i need to be able to go as many levels deep as whats in the database.

For example with the below function i can only get "Parent > Child" whereas i need to be able to go "Parent > Child > Child > Child".

**issue 2**

With the old mysql function i used to be able to count how many children there was going to be and if there was children it would built the menu with a drop down if not it would build the menu as just a plain link.

Is this possible with arrays? if so how can i achieve it?.

The function in question.

```
function BuildMenu(){
    function ChildMenu($Pages,$parent){
        $tree=null;
            $tree .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";  
                for($i = 0; $i < count($Pages); $i++) {
                    if($Pages[$i]['page_parent'] == $parent){
                        $tree .=  "<li><a href='" . $Pages[$i]['page_slug'] . "' title=''>" . $Pages[$i]['page_title'] . "</a></li>";               
                    }
                }   
            $tree .= "</ul>";
        return $tree;
    }           

    function ParentMenu($Pages){
        $tree=null;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($Pages); $i++) {
            if($Pages[$i]['page_parent'] == 0 AND $Pages[$i]['page_disablemenu'] <> 'yes'){
                $tree .= "<li class='dropdown'>";   
                    $tree .=  "<a data-toggle='dropdown' href='" . $Pages[$i]['page_slug'] . "' title=''>" . $Pages[$i]['page_title'] . "<span class='caret'></span></a>";  
                    $tree .=  ChildMenu($Pages,$Pages[$i]['page_idno']);
                $tree .=  "</li>";
            }
        }   
        return $tree;
    }   
    return ParentMenu($this->ApplicationPages);
}
```

The table currently looks like the below

page_idno | page_slug | page_title | page_parent

```
1     |   test    |     Test   |     0

2     |   test2   |    Test 2  |     1
```

Comment: Can you show us some data?

Comment: as in how the table looks?

Comment: As in how the `parent > child > child > child` relationship is defined

Comment: @Michel i have updated the question, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. `Page 3` in your example can have `page_parent: 2`, which has `page_parent: 1` So the relation is `1 > 2 > 3` ?  But what do you want in the ParentMenu? Only the top level pages (i.e. 1) or all pages that have a child (1 and 2)? And what goes in the ChildMenu? Only the direct children (2 for page 1) or all children (2 and 3).